# Writing a Cost Function

Tags: r, function

I have a problem involving writing a cost function. 
The information I have been given is: 'Charles has taken over a market stall where he sells fresh fish. Each morning he buys fish from the wholesaler at a cost of $4 per kg up to the first 100 kg
and $2.5 per kg for anything above 100 kg.'

This is what I've written so far:

```
cost= function(n)

{
  if (n<=100)
    cost = n*4

  if (n>100)
    cost = 2.5*(n-100) +100*4

}

cost(5)
```

It doesn't run, where have I gone wrong? Please may I have some help.

Thank you.

Comment: Why the [tag:fish] tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just neglected to return a value from your function:

```
cost <- function(n) {
    total <- 0
    if (n <= 100) {
        total <- n*4
    }
    else {
        total = 2.5*(n-100) + 100*4
    }

    return(total)
}

cost(5)
```

### Demo

R has rules which determine if there is an implicit return value and what that would be, but using an explicit `return` statement is always a good thing, as it makes it clear what your function is actually doing.

Note: Using `ifelse` we can actually handle this entire logic in a single line of code:

```
cost <- ifelse(n <= 100, n*4, 2.5*(n-100) + 100*4)
```